# can I do unit testing of an ASP.net MVC project from a console program?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm getting started on unit testing in an ASP.NET MVC project. What I've seen of unit testing methodology suggests that people create different controllers to run the unit tests, which suggests that the unit testing occurs within the MVC environment. Is there a way to set up enough of an environment so that you can link to the MVC dll as a project from a console application and call controller tests from the console program? That would avoid having to have a local IIS running to do test, etc.

thanks!

john

Comment: unit tests do not run in the "MVC environment."  They will run within the scope of the test runner, be that nunit, resharper,....  Unit tests are just a class library.

Comment: You should really read up on the documentation available [Creating Unit Tests for ASP.NET MVC Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs)

Answer (score 3):

While you *can* run units tests from a console app (or MVC app for that matter), you shouldn't.

As Fran mentioned, you should be running them from within your Test Framework Application or Visual Studio itself... There are plenty references for this;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer